# VS2010 Just in time debugger doesn't show entire message

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, visual-studio-debugging

I often get the Just-in-time debugger window, and most often no message is shown, but some times I can't see the entire exception, which could be useful.

[image: Example]

When I try to run the debugger I always get an error that another debugger is already atached, which leads me nowhere. The window is not resizable and the text can't be copied.

I'm developing in VS 2010 + C# + Silverlight, and it happens when running via VS.

Any insights?

Comment: try ctrl-c and paste into notepad. The contents of the dialog including the entire exception message should be copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get "another debugger is already atached" because you are already in debug mode and your browser's process attached to your code.

**Firstly,
Handle global exceptions in your App.xaml**

Secondly, In your browser open developer inspector. (F12 for most of browser) and watch console.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception(v=vs.95).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3

using System.IO; // FileNotFoundException
using System.Windows; // Application, StartupEventArgs, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs

```
 namespace SilverlightApplication
   {
   public partial class App : Application
    {
    public App()
    {
        this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;
        this.UnhandledException += this.Application_UnhandledException;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RootVisual = new Page();
    }

    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, 
        ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ExceptionObject is FileNotFoundException)
        {
            // Inform the user

            // Recover from the error
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }

        // Exception is unrecoverable so stop the application and allow the 
        // Silverlight plug-in control to detect and process the exception.
    }
}
```

}

**Secondly, In your browser open developer inspector. (F12 for most of browser) and watch console.** The message comes from index.aspx which your xap hosted. There is a silverlighterror js function response it.

```
            function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
        var appSource = "";
        if (sender != null && sender != 0) {
          appSource = sender.getHost().Source;
        }

        var errorType = args.ErrorType;
        var iErrorCode = args.ErrorCode;

        if (errorType == "ImageError" || errorType == "MediaError") {
          return;
        }

        var errMsg = "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " +  appSource + "\n" ;

        errMsg += "Code: "+ iErrorCode + "    \n";
        errMsg += "Category: " + errorType + "       \n";
        errMsg += "Message: " + args.ErrorMessage + "     \n";

        if (errorType == "ParserError") {
            errMsg += "File: " + args.xamlFile + "     \n";
            errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
            errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
        }
        else if (errorType == "RuntimeError") {           
            if (args.lineNumber != 0) {
                errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Position: " +  args.charPosition + "     \n";
            }
            errMsg += "MethodName: " + args.methodName + "     \n";
        }

        throw new Error(errMsg);
    }
```

**Finally, always ensure that (if exist) in your web project's settings.In Web Section there is a Silverlight Checkbox for debugging. It must be checked for debugging attachment.**

**One more clue:** *In VS Ctrl + Alt + E and then select CLR exceptions , when you launch you will get more details about error. But do it where error exactly occurs. Because it sometimes give non-errors,but caught by debugger.*

Hope helps!